# Не могу найти ошибку в коде при рефакторинге

Tags: javascript

Нужно избавится от логических операторов && и ||, заменив их на более читаемые конструкции if / else. Исходный код:

```
function getBoolean(a, b, c, d) {
  return a && a > b && c > d && a < c || b && b > a && c > a || c > d && d && d < a;
}
```

Вот что у меня получилось:

```
function getBoolean(a, b, c, d) {
    if(a < b){
      if(c > d){
        if(a < c){
          return true 
        }
      }
    }
    if(b > a){
      if(c > a){
        return true
      }
    }
    if (c > d){
      if(d < a){
        return true
      }
    }
    else{
      return false
    }
}
```

Все работает правильно, только input: a = 0, b = 0, c = 54, d = 3 должен возвращать false, а у меня возвращается undefined.
Где ошибка?

Comment: с какой целью два одинаковых условия: a<b и b>a?

Comment: дай переменным нормальные говорящие названия и все будет намного легче

Answer (score 0):

При этих данных выполнение заходит в эту ветку:

```
if (c > d){
      if(d < a){
        return true
      }
    }
```

Но поскольку `d  < a` дает нам false, то на этом выполнение функции и прикращается. И return для такого случая отсутствует.

Answer (score 0):

Да я подумал и оптимизировал. Вот так получилось

```
function getBoolean(a, b, c, d) {
  if (a < b){
    return true;
  } if (a < d){
    return false;
  } if (c > d) {
    return true;
  } if (a === c) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Тут невооруженным взглядом видно, что учтено далеко не все. Проверьте на 10, 0, 1, 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!a || !b || !d) return false;
if (a > b && c > d && a < c) return true;
if (b > a && c > a ) return true;
if (c > d && d < a) return true;
return false
```